# Using osm2pgsql default.style file on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, directory, gis, openstreetmap

I am trying to use osm2pgsql on Windows 7. However, when I try to do a conversion, it gives an error since it is looking for default.style at this location:

```
/usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style
```

Obviously this location does not exist in Windows so where should default.style be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide it via `-S`

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/utils/export/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql.c has all the outputs you need, or reading the --help from the tools itself also gives the information

Comment: Thanks! I used it like this: osm2pgsql -U postgres -s -S ./default.style c:\data\denmark.osm